# Error ploting N index vs thickness for TM and TE modes using maxwells full equation

Tags: python, physics

[image]

So my Python code for this is here, it only displays the graph at `m = 4` and I need it to display for `m = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import root

# Given parameters
wavelength = 1550  # Wavelength in nm
nc = 1.10
nf = 2.55
ns = 1.94
T_range = np.linspace(0.01, 5, 500)  # Avoid T = 0 to prevent division by zero
mode_numbers = np.arange(0, 5)  # Modes to consider: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
k0 = 2 * np.pi / wavelength  # Free-space wavenumber

# Initialize arrays to store results
TE_modes = np.zeros((len(mode_numbers), len(T_range)))
TM_modes = np.zeros((len(mode_numbers), len(T_range)))

# Function to calculate effective index equation
def effective_index_eq(neff, m, T, polarization):
    knaught = k0 * T
    if polarization == 'TE':
        return np.tan(knaught * np.sqrt(neff**2 - nf**2)) + np.tan(knaught * np.sqrt(neff**2 - ns**2)) + m * np.pi
    elif polarization == 'TM':
        return np.tan(knaught * np.sqrt(neff**2 - nf**2)) - np.tan(knaught * np.sqrt(neff**2 - ns**2)) - m * np.pi

# Calculate TE and TM modes for all modes and thicknesses
for i, m in enumerate(mode_numbers):
    for j, T in enumerate(T_range):
        TE_solution = root(effective_index_eq, nf, args=(m, T, 'TE'))
        TM_solution = root(effective_index_eq, nf, args=(m, T, 'TM'))
        TE_modes[i, j] = TE_solution.x[0] if TE_solution.success else np.nan
        TM_modes[i, j] = TM_solution.x[0] if TM_solution.success else np.nan

# Create separate graphs for TE and TM modes
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# Plot effective indices vs. thickness for TE modes
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
for i, m in enumerate(mode_numbers):
    plt.plot(T_range, TE_modes[i], linestyle='-', label=f'TE Mode m={m}')

plt.xlabel('Waveguide Thickness (µm)')
plt.ylabel('Effective Index (N)')
plt.title('Effective Index vs. Thickness for TE Modes')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

# Plot effective indices vs. thickness for TM modes
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
for i, m in enumerate(mode_numbers):
    plt.plot(T_range, TM_modes[i], linestyle='--', label=f'TM Mode m={m}')

plt.xlabel('Waveguide Thickness (µm)')
plt.ylabel('Effective Index (N)')
plt.title('Effective Index vs. Thickness for TM Modes')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is more of a programming question than physics-related. I believe it is better suited for the StackOverflow site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about debugging software instead of physics

Comment: Um. I guess you're right. Ill go to stackoverflow